# cannot get ajax responseText with Phalcon

Tags: php, ajax, phalcon

I want to call an `ajax` and display its response :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test() {
    var pk = $('#salle_code').val();
    var donne = {pk:pk};
    var ret = $.ajax({
            data: donne,
            type: "POST",
            url:  "<?php echo HTTP_AJAX ?>salle/testAjax.php",
            async: false
         }).responseText;
    return $.trim(ret);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#salle_code').on("blur", function() {
        if ($('#salle_code').val() != "") {
            alert(""+test());
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Code of the ajax :

```
<?php
$critere = array();
$critere['salle_code'] = $_POST['pk'];
$ret = Salle::lireParCritere($critere);
echo "111111111111111";
?>
```

At runtime the alert show a blank result ! So how to work with Phalcon and ajax and models ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Klay there was a very simple solution : I created an ajax action inside the controller of the actual view.

Answer (score 2):

use following code and check browser console for response

```
 $.ajax({
    data: donne,
    type: "POST",
    url:  "<?php echo HTTP_AJAX ?>salle/testAjax.php",
    async: false
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
    error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(textStatus + " : " + errorThrown)
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need define a route for AJAX request, e.g. `/salle/test`:

```
$router->add('/salle/test', [
    'controller' => 'salle',
    'action' => 'test',
))->beforeMatch(function ($uri, $route) {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

then create your action:

```
public function testAction()
{
    // some work ..

    $this->response->setJsonContent(json_encode(['foo' => 'bar']));
    return $this->response;
}
```

then test:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        var response = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {},
            url: '/salle/test',
            success:function(results) {
                console.log(results);
            }
        });

        return response;
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log(test());
    });
</script>
```